# What's the best way to access SQLiteDatabase object in an activity

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the best way to quickly get `SQLiteDatabase` object in an activity to quickly run rawQuery(). I m using the ContentProvider generated by MotoDev studio which is probably the quicker way to get through generating CPs and other database code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Content Providers,It's best way to access database.In Android 2.3.3 Source code,They can use same method for access database more information see this links
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: I know ContentProvider query() is good. But here I want to use rawQuery for a complex query need.

Comment: You have to implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried generating the SQLiteOpenHelper? MOTODEV Studio can do that for you, ant it allows you to get an SQLiteDatabase by using the method getReadableDatabase().